# Python : find substring1 and if it does not exist then find substring2

Tags: python

For Example:

my string looks like this:

1.1.0-feature

1.1.0-feature

1.1.0-feature

1.1.0-feature

1.1.0-feature

1.1.0-mainline

1.1.0-feature

1.1.0-feature

1.1.0-feature

1.1.0-mainline

1.1.0-mainline

v1.5.0-mainline

substring1 = mainline

substring2 = feature

if substrin1 exist in string:

```
 print string and do not enter to else statement
```

else check if substring2 exist in string

```
 print string
```

Output should be:

1.1.0-mainline

Comment: Please fix your formatting, add quotes and list parentheses, if any `[...]`. Is that a list of strings, or a pandas dataframe string column, or what?

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to do the same thing under both conditions, there's no need for two `if` statements, a single one will do.  The `or` is short circuiting so if the first condition is `True` the second won't be checked.

```
if substring1 in string or substring2 in string:
    print(string)
```

Comment: No, I fist need to check if substring1 is present, if its not present then I want to check if substring2 is present.

Comment: @Muks read my answer again, that's exactly what it does.

Comment: I dont want to print substring2 if substring1 is present. Right now it is printing both substring1 and substring2.

Comment: @Muks your intention is not at all clear.  Based on the question, you want to print the string only once, if either substring1 or substring2 are found within it.  Have you tried the code I proposed here?

Comment: Yes I have tried and It print both substring1 and substring2.

Comment: I want to print string for substring2 only if substring1 is not present.

Comment: @QAE then you need to be clear about that in your question.  If you can't describe the problem clearly enough that another human can understand it, how do you expect to explain it to a computer?

Comment: @QAE P.S. don't change your user name a few minutes after posting a question.  It makes for a very confusing comment chain.

Comment: Read my question again: I have clearly mentioned that "print string and do not enter to else statement".

Comment: @QAE do you know how `else` works?  If the `if` condition is taken, the `else` part is skipped automatically.  You question is very much NOT clear.  And I'm done arguing about it, if you want an answer figure it out yourself.

Comment: u r not the only one who can answer this question. off course I will figure out by myself or someone else will answer. Thanks anyway!!